# Waypoint mission is not Pausing

Tags: android, dji-sdk

in `onExecutionUpdate`, I was checking `isWaypointReached` status. if the status is false the execution gets stopped and it's not giving any updates after that from the `onExecutionUpdate` callback.

```
@Override

public void onExecutionUpdate(final WaypointMissionExecutionEvent executionEvent) {

    int waypoint_size = executionEvent.getProgress().totalWaypointCount;
    int target_waypoint_index = executionEvent.getProgress().targetWaypointIndex;

    if (waypoint_size - 1 == target_waypoint_index) {
        if (executionEvent.getProgress().isWaypointReached == true) {
            if (executionEvent.getProgress().executeState.toString().equals("FINISHED_ACTION")) {
                setResultToToast("Aircraft reached at waypoint location");
                stopWaypointMission();
            }
        }

    } else {
        if (executionEvent.getProgress().isWaypointReached == true) {
            if (executionEvent.getProgress().executeState.toString().equals("BEGIN_ACTION")) {
                setResultToToast("aircraft reached at location " + "" + target_waypoint_index);
                pauseWaypointMission();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

> 2019-05-29 12:03:28.442 12792-12834/? E/exe event: cur state=EXECUTING
>   pre state=EXECUTING progress=total count=2 target index=0 is reached=
>   false state=INITIALIZING error=null
>
> 2019-05-29 12:03:28.443 12792-12834/? E/waypoint_reached: false

Answer (score 0):

which dji sdk you are working on?  MSDK OSDK?

For DJI mission planning there are plenty of bugs. So you have to show the error message that you are receving, E.g

```
0xE9    Point data not enough
0xEA    WayPoint mission data not enough
0xEB    WayPoints not enough
```

For mine case, I ask the drone to stop by calling mission::stop. it reply me with Point not enough. High chance is the ACK inside get stuck. I`m currently liaising with DJI for solving this issue.

If you can provide me with an accurate description and your error code, I can help you get the solution.

[image]